# How can I use IF in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

```
IF Dealdate = @DealDate
```

I use `IF` command in a stored procedure. In that command I check a column from a table with a variable but it can't execute and returns this error:

> *Invalid column name 'Dealdate'.*

Comment: Plesee show the full code and the appropriate table schema

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna check if a row in your table exists with `DealDate` equal to `@DealDate`, this is how you would do it,

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DealDate = @DealDate)
BEGIN
END
```

Comment: @njk what are the chances that this will work for his DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check for a value in a table. you need to check for the value of column in the table like so 
IF EXISTS (SELECT DealDate FROM MyTable WHERE DealDate = @DealDate)
BEGIN
   --your logic goes here.
END

but you are getting error "Invalid column name 'Dealdate'"
which shows that your code " if Dealdate = @DealDate " does not specify what is Dealdate so SQL sever is giving this error as Dealdate is not a variable so SQL Server tries to search for a column with such a name but since table name is not specified in our code it gives you this error.